# undefined method `in_array' for #<Mongoid::Matchers::Validations::ValidateInclusionOfMatcher>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, shoulda

I have been looking around to know how to test a validates_inclusion_of model validations, and now I would like to test it. But there is an error that I don't know how to solve.  Is this method deprecated? Is there any alternative?

My model:

```
class SomeName
  include Mongoid::xxx (some mongoid includes)

  field :time_zone
  validates :time_zone, inclusion: { in: ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys }
end
```

My test:

```
 describe SomeName do
   subject { build(:some_name) }

   it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }
 end
```

My shoulda-matchers version:

```
shoulda-matchers (2.8.0)
```

My error:

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `in_array' for #<Mongoid::Matchers::Validations::ValidateInclusionOfMatcher:0x007fb2be592590>
```

Comment: It seems you are also using `mongoid-rspec` gem? They both defines `validate_inclusion_of`, which one you'll get depends on order they are included.

Comment: good answer! why don't you put this as an answer so I can give you extra power?

Comment: Mmmm, extra power. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the error message, it seems you have also installed `mongoid-rspec` gem which is also defining `validates_inclusion_of` method. In your case it is included after `shoulda-matchers` and hence it overrides the method.

Two options here - either change the order of inclusion of those two modules (which then will give you shoulda-matcher matcher) or adopt your code to mongoid-rspec implementation:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:time_zone).to_allow(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }
```

Comment: I changed the order and it worked for this test, but I started having other kind of problems with "belong_to". So finally, I did it in the brave way (maybe a helper would be better, but it made me feel as if I was doing monkeypatching): it { is_expected.to Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::ValidateInclusionOfMatcher.new(:time_zone).in_array(ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.keys) }

Comment: mongoid-rspec docs suggest using to_allow like:  it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:locale).to_allow([:en, :ru]) }
see https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-rspec?tab=readme-ov-file#validation-matchers